# my model doesn't move from the origin, or moves or rotates ONCE and then returns to the origin

Tags: game-engine

I exported my scene with a simple plane and a animated mesh into 2.73 from 2.66a and now the mesh doesn't move from the origin, it looks like if it wants to move or rotate but it remains in  the origin, or if it moves when i press another key to rotate or move, the model returns into origin. Please help

Here is the blend file:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33673

Perhaps this could work:

[How do you import a rigged character from one blender file to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21496/how-do-you-import-a-rigged-character-from-one-blender-file-to-another)

Now i am trying to clear parent between armature and mesh nd rig again. Actually the walking animation was easy to reproduce and not very accurate. hmmmm

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a link to the blend file via: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Problem solved!!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question using the answer box below.

Comment: No, still problematic, i thought i could change location of the object via the animation, but then i was forced to make huge animation clip! Still unresolved. The animation is there, however...idk :(

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!! I linked model and armature from 2.66a, applied proxy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and rigged and animated again the mesh. All worked fine!!